# Difference between Left Factoring and Left Recursion

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, compiler-construction, topdown

What is the difference between `Left Factoring` and `Left Recursion` ? I understand that `Left factoring` is a predictive top down parsing technique. But I get confused when I hear these two terms.

Answer (score 76):

Left factoring is removing the common left factor that appears in two productions of the same non-terminal. It is done to avoid back-tracing by the parser. Suppose the parser has a look-ahead, consider this example:

```
A -> qB | qC
```

where `A`, `B` and `C` are non-terminals and `q` is a sentence.

In this case, the parser will be confused as to which of the two productions to choose and it might have to back-trace. After left factoring, the grammar is converted to:

```
A -> qD
D -> B | C
```

In this case, a parser with a look-ahead will always choose the right production.

Left recursion is a case when the left-most non-terminal in a production of a non-terminal is the non-terminal itself (direct left recursion) or through some other non-terminal definitions, rewrites to the non-terminal again (indirect left recursion).

Consider these examples:

```
(1) A -> Aq (direct)

(2) A -> Bq
    B -> Ar (indirect)
```

Left recursion has to be removed if the parser performs top-down parsing.

Answer (score 31):

**Left Factoring** is a grammar transformation technique. It consists in "factoring out" prefixes which are common to two or more productions.

For example, going from:

> A → α β | α γ

to:

> A → α A'
>
> A' → β | γ

---

**Left Recursion** is a property a grammar has whenever you can derive from a given variable (non terminal) a rhs that begins with the same variable, in one or more steps.

For example:

> A → A α

or

> A → B α
>
> B → A γ

There is a grammar transformation technique called *Elimination of left recursion*, which provides a method to generate, given a left recursive grammar, another grammar that is equivalent and is not left recursive.

---

The relationship/confusion between both terms probably derives from the fact that both transformation techniques may need to be applied to a grammar before being able to derive a predictive top down parser for it.

Answer (score 12):

This is the way I've seen the two terms used:

1. Left recursion: when one or more productions can be reached from themselves with no tokens consumed in-between.
2. Left factoring: a process of transformation, turning the grammar from a left-recursive form to an equivalent non-left-recursive form.

Answer (score 9):

left factor :

Let the given grammar : 
A-->ab1 | ab2 | ab3

1) we can see that, for every production, there is a common prefix & if we choose any production here, it is not confirmed that we will not need to backtrack.
2) it is non deterministic, because we cannot choice any production and be assured that we will reach at our desired string by making the correct parse tree. 
but if we rewrite the grammar in a way that is deterministic and also leaves us flexible enough to convert it into any string that is possible without backtracking, it will be:

A  --> aA', 
A' --> b1 | b2| b3

now if we are asked to make the parse tree for string ab2 and now we don't need back tracking. Because we can always choose the correct production when we get A' thus we will generate the correct parse tree.

Left recursion :

A --> Aa | b 
here it is clear that the left child of A will always be A if we choose the first production,this is left recursion .because , A is calling itself over and over again . 
the generated string from this grammar is : 
ba*
since this cannot be in a grammar ... we eliminate the left recursion by writing :

A --> bA'
A' --> E | aA'
now we will not have left recursion and also we can generate ba* .

Answer (score 5):

**Left Recursion:**
A grammar is left recursive if it has a nonterminal A such that there is a derivation **A -> Aα | β** where α and β are sequences of terminals and nonterminals that do not start with A.

While designing a top down-parser, if the left recursion exist in the grammar then the parser falls in an infinite loop, here because A is trying to match A itself, which is not possible.
We can eliminate the above left recursion by rewriting the offending production. As-

**A -> βA'**

**A' -> αA' | epsilon**

**Left Factoring:** Left factoring is required to eliminate non-determinism of a grammar. Suppose a grammar, **S -> abS | aSb**

Here, S is deriving the same terminal a in the production rule(two alternative choices for S), which follows non-determinism. We can rewrite the production to defer the decision of S as-

**S -> aS'**

**S' -> bS | Sb**

Thus, S' can be replaced for bS or Sb

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to differentiate between both terms:

- Left Recursion:
  When leftmost Element of a production is the Producing element itself (Non Terminal Element).

e.g. **A -> Aα / Aβ**

- Left Factoring:
  When leftmost Element of a production (Terminal element) is repeated in the same production.

e.g. **A -> αB / αC**

**Furthermore,**
If a Grammar is Left Recursive, it might result into infinite loop hence we need to *Eliminate Left Recursion*.

If a Grammar is Left Factoring, it confuses the parser hence we need to *Remove Left Factoring as well*.

Answer (score 1):

left recursion:= when left hand non terminal is same as right hand non terminal. 
Example:
A->A&|B  where & is alpha.
We can remove left ricursion using rewrite this production as like.

A->BA'
A'->&A'|€

Left factor mean productn should not non deterministic. .
Example:
A->&A|&B|&C